# return code vs exit status

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I read the docs for the subprocess module of Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

I am confused.

> The CalledProcessError object will have the **return code** in the returncode attribute.

Some lines below:

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'exit 1' returned non-zero **exit status** 1

What the name of this thing?

*return code* or *exit status*?

Comment: Both are one & the same thing - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil thank you for this link. Since the wikipedia article has the title "Exit Status", I think that this name is preferred.

Comment: @guettli usage can depend upon context rather than preference, and the article had to be called something. Both are commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are one & the same thing - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status